# what is invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'startTime'

Tags: django, django-models, timestamp, unix-timestamp

i am getting an error of invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'startTime'

```
 hour=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((int(str('startTime')))/1000).strftime('%H')
```

startTime is Integerfield in my model which contains 13 digit unix timestamp
this is my query code

```
 timehour = InteractionWith.objects.values(
    #hour=ExtractHour('startTime')
    hour=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((int(str('startTime')))/1000).strftime('%H')
).annotate(
    times=Count('pk')
).order_by('hour')
```

Comment: ``'startTime'`` is a string; it does not refer to nor access any field of an object or database.

Comment: how should i make it refer to my django model field

Comment: what is wrong with `ExtractHour`?

Comment: it doesnt work as my startTime is a integerfield and also i tried it in cmd prompt  readable=ExtractHour((1593169750))  , print (readable) output was ExtractHour(Value(1593169750))